# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Error prompted when execute `console.log($obj.longurl)` from the Chrome Developer Console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { 
$.ajax.complete 
L jquery.min.js:19
N
```

Below is the script I execute from a HTML page and submit a form to call an external PHP file.

Javascript is called from **http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js**

```
$('#shortener').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#status').text('');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#shortener').serialize(),
        url: $('#shortener').attr('action'),
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            $obj = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.response);
            if ($obj.loginResult == "Passed") {
                ($('#longurl').val() === "") ? console.log("Empty longurl") : console.log($obj.longurl);
            } else {
                $('#status').text("Login Failed");
            };
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP

```
echo json_encode(array('loginResult' =>'Passed'));
echo json_encode(array('longurl' => BASE_HREF . $shortened_url));
```

typeof `$obj.longurl` is string but don't know why it can be returned to the `$('#shortener').val()`, anyone have similar experience and have the solution?

Comment: As a side note, try to indent your code properly next time, the way it is is  a bit hard to read, especially when the major problem is with the block syntax, which will be easier to solve if the code is properly indented.

Comment: Have you checked that your response is valid JSON?

Comment: merge 2 arrays and put one echo json_encode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PHP code is producing invalid JSON. You are basically echoing two JSON encoded objects after each other, which overall results in invalid JSON. It will look like:

```
{"loginResult": "Passed"} {"longurl": "<some URL>"}
```

The second `{` is the syntax error.

It should either be an array of objects (although that would be a strange structure)

```
[{"loginResult": "Passed"}, {"longurl": "<some URL>"}]
```

or one object

```
{"loginResult": "Passed", "longurl": "<some URL>"}
```

Create and encode *one* array:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'loginResult' => 'Passed',
    'longurl' => BASE_HREF . $shortened_url
));
```

---

Another problem might be that, at least officially, the [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) passed to the complete callback doesn't have a `.response` property. Since you also already set the `dataType: 'json'` option, there is no need for you to parse the response explicitly.

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('#shortener').serialize(),
    url: $('#shortener').attr('action'),
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.loginResult == "Passed") {
        ($('#longurl').val() === "") ? console.log("Empty longurl") : console.log(data.longurl);
    } else {
        $('#status').text("Login Failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: I finally create an array variable and push the key/value to array and echo the array variable, for example

echo json_encode($arr);

Comment: .response is one of the properties of the jqXHR when I do the console.log(jqXHR). I cannot get the object value if no JSON.parse() apply.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: You can choose whatever works for you. I just mentioned it because `.response` is not listed as a property in the documentation (at least I didn't see it). And if you use a success event handler (which is what `.done` does) instead of a complete event handler, then you can access the already parsed data (because that's what `dataType: 'json'`, it passes the parsed data to the success event handler).

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling's comment.